# Socket io android handshake failed as client

Tags: java, android, node.js, multithreading, sockets

Im trying to connect to my friends Nodejs socket server. im doing this with this library: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/

Im trying to use this in a background service. and got this part working.

I also have the socket in a new thread(i dont know if this is correct)

the code looks like this:

```
  @Override
    public void run() {
        SocketIO socket = null;
        try {

            socket = new SocketIO("http://api.speebee.com:3000");

        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
            }
        });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this results in the following error:

```
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app 

I/System.out﹕ an Error occured
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:292)
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
05-21 11:34:23.205    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.speebee.com:3000/socket.io/1/
05-21 11:34:23.214    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
05-21 11:34:23.214    5661-5806/com.geniusgentlemen.gp_android_app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
```

if tryied setting the default ssh but this didnt work. How can i get this to work?

Comment: Do you have the server logs? Looks like you're running into a bad handshake, which could be for a number of reasons.

Comment: i shall get the server logs

Comment: The log's are empty and redis-cli monitor has no connection

Answer (score 0):

[Socket IO Android Client Example](https://github.com/HemrajLodha/SocketIO-Android-Client-Example)

[Socket IO Server Example](https://github.com/HemrajLodha/SocketIO-Server-Example)

Check above links for complete client/Server code with connection and messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need check handshake if is it default(`/socket.io`)? to set custom you need to put it in **IO.Options.path**

```
Options opts = new IO.Options(); 
opts.path = "/custom/socket.io"
Socket socket = IO.socket("https://api.com", opts)
```