# Socket Io With Android Service

Tags: android, sockets, service, threadpool, background-task

Good day. I have a very specific issue considering the Socket IO library for android and it's service.

Important to mention that my device is huawei p8 lite which i am testing on.

Here it goes :

• I have a socket Io library which is being initialized inside the service i have created

• I set the listener to the socket io for new messages

• Everything works like a char if the application is not killed within the process trey by the user.

• The purpose of service was to keep the socket IO connection alive even if the application is killed so the user will be notified about new messages.

• As soon as the application is being killed,the Socket IO connection has been disconnected

No matter what i try,and i try all of possible ways :  Isolating the process of Service,giving another process for the service,Starting it sticky,starting it not sticky recreating as soon as the service destroys and etc.

The only thing which has worked is the startForeground() method,but i do not want to use it as it will go under the design principles and plus i do not want to show any notification about the running service.

My question is the next :  Can anyone help me out and tell me how can i keep the Socket IO connection alive even if the application is killed?

Here is the code of the service.

```
package com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class SocketService extends Service {
    private Socket mSocket;
    public static final String TAG = SocketService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "on created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "start command", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mSocket.on("newMessageReceived", onNewMessage);
        mSocket.connect();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            String message = args[0].toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "call: new message ");
            sendGeneralNotification(getApplicationContext(), "1", "new message", message, null);
        }
    };

    private void sendGeneralNotification(Context context, String uniqueId,
                                         String title, String contentText,
                                         @Nullable Class<?> resultClass) {

        NotificationManager notificationManagerCompat = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);


        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setGroup("faskfjasfa");
        builder.setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .setSummaryText(title)
                .setBigContentTitle(title)
                .bigText(contentText)
        );

        Intent requestsViewIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        requestsViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        requestsViewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent requestsViewPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Integer.valueOf(uniqueId), requestsViewIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(requestsViewPending);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        builder.setShowWhen(true);
        android.app.Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(Integer.valueOf(uniqueId), notification);
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        Notification notification;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setColor(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.material_deep_teal_500))
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        return notification;
    }
}
```

And NO,i do not want to use neither firebase nor any 3rd party made ones as i am using one now and i suffer from delays,from non-received notifications and etc,and i will make my own small one ways better. Thanks everyone for you'r time and patience.

Comment: hmm i guess i have asked really horrible question huh? No one even closer tried to asnwer or give a smallest hint at all

Comment: Hi Volo, I too facing exactly same issue did you found any way to achieve it,if so can you share it as your own answer,Thank you in advance.

Comment: Find complete server and client side solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099689/5063805

Answer (score 3):

Implementing Socket.io in the background is not the best of ideas. Socket.io has an active ping to your server. Using it for a short period is okay, but in the background it is a NO.

The best way to solve your problem is to combine Socket.io and [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)/GCM topics to emit a broadcast. On the users device, detect if there is an active Socket.io connection, if one exits ignore the FCM else execute the FCM.

Comment: How? could have and example or repo in github pls. I know that with fcm coul receive notifications in background and killed mode , but where put this code because i saw other examples that use 

**socket.io in a service** 
other examples create other class that extends Application

Comment: Indeed, the official socketio documentation says this : "Socket.IO is not meant to be used in a background service for mobile applications."
It also explains why:
"The Socket.IO library keeps an open TCP connection to the server, which may result in a high battery drain for your users. Please use a dedicated messaging platform like FCM for this use case."

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method in your service class and try with this.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);


Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());

    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    restartServiceIntent.putExtra("NODE CONNECTED", true);
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().
            getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);
}
```

this method will call when you kill the app and again restart your background service.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "systemService");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}
```

and do not forget permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: try this in the service , and do not forget permission :     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: Please add the explanation to your answer using the `edit` link